# Mapping a https://... as a local logic drive?

Tags: c#

I can map a network share point to a local logical drive by using net.exe like this:

```
net use J: \\cnf001\test\folder1 /user: ...
```

I build a C# lib to use Process to simulate the mapping. Now I have a case I need to map: a share point in "My Computer"->"My Network Places"->[share node], where "share node" is in the format https://...

I cannot use net.exe any more, or I am not sure what parameters I can use if possible? Anyway, is it possible to build map drive for this case? How? Do I need some other tools

Comment: My client has a https://.. share point available with user name and pwd. What I need to do is to put a text file there in a folder. I guess I need to build a map drive first, then use System.IO to output file there.

Comment: I guess I cannot use net.exe but I can use ftp to transfer the file. Any information about its parameters to send file to a host so that I can invoke the process in C#?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this if the server at the HTTP(s) supports WebDAV.  WebDAV is available on most web platforms so it shouldn't be an issue to enable it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

Comment: The question is about the *client*, not the _server_.

Comment: This is an answer about the client as well.  WebDAV is a widely supported protocol for just this type of stuff; mounting and accessing a file system via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following article: [Reading contents of Web Folders in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ReadWebFolderContent.aspx).
In a nutshell, the folders in My Network Places are just file system shortcuts located in Documents and Settings\$USER$\NetHood (XP) / Users\$USER$\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts (Vista).

And regarding your comment on using FTP - you can use System.Net.FtpWebRequest class or System.Net.WebClient class.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you need a third party tool. For example [DriveOnWeb](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Network_and_Internet/FTP_and_Archie_Clients/DriveOnWeb.html). I used an OEM version, which only works with my ISP, but it works great.